# how to pass less parameters to a function for sql queries in python

Tags: python, postgresql, parameter-passing, psycopg2

Here is my code. I just want to update of the title of the book and the name of the author and I want other parameter values remain the same. I get an error as below. What should I pass for not changing parameters? I have tried to pass just variable names as year and isbn but it did not work. I searched a lot in similar questions but it did not help.

```
def update(id, title, author, year, isbn):
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='' user= password='' host='localhost' port='5432' ")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("UPDATE dnr SET title=%s, author=%s, year=%s, isbn=%s WHERE id=%s", (title, author, year, isbn, id))
conn.commit()
conn.close

update(1, "The Sky", "Jonh Smith")
```

Error:

```
TypeError: update() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'year' and 'isbn'
```

Comment: on the python function side, you need to set default values for the arguments. I'd recommend `None`. Someone else will need to help on how to get the sql query right

Comment: Actually, I tried "None" but then it prints out the remaining columns as None which should remain as before. By the way, it worked for "search" function to put not-changing parameters(year, isbn) as None but i think i need something different for "update" function.

Comment: If your question was answered please mark it as [solved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

You can use default values for optional parameters and check if they are set, adjusting the query and data accordinly.

```py
def update(id, title, author, year=None, isbn=None):
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='' user= password='' host='localhost' port='5432' ")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    query = "UPDATE dnr SET title=%s, author=%s"
    data = [title, author]
    if year is not None:
        query += ", year=%s"
        data.append(year)
    if isbn is not None:
        query += ", isbn=%s"
        data.append(isbn)
    query += " WHERE id=%s"
    data.append(id)
    cur.execute(query, data)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close

update(1, "The Sky", "Jonh Smith")
```